# Generated query copy/pasted to shell returns results but no results in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very peculiar case where my generated MySQL query returns a result in MySQL shell when I copy and paste over the echo, but PHP does not seem to be able to pull any results over in the while fetch_assoc loop.

I've been staring at this for hours, but I just don't understand why PHP is not sending to MySQL the `query` string that it generated.

```
//$mysql_connection = mysql_connect([...])

$pos = pos2arr($kp);

$pos_others[] = ($pos[0]+1).', '.$pos[1].', '.($pos[2]+1);
$pos_others[] = ($pos[0]-1).', '.$pos[1].', '.($pos[2]-1);
$pos_others[] = ($pos[0]-1).', '.$pos[1].', '.($pos[2]+1);
$pos_others[] = ($pos[0]+1).', '.$pos[1].', '.($pos[2]-1);
$pos_others[] = ($pos[0]+1).', '.$pos[1].', '.$pos[2];
$pos_others[] = ($pos[0]-1).', '.$pos[1].', '.$pos[2];
$pos_others[] = $pos[0].', '.$pos[1].', '.($pos[2]+1);
$pos_others[] = $pos[0].', '.$pos[1].', '.($pos[2]-1);

$query = "SELECT * FROM allplayer WHERE venueuuid='".$venueuuid."' AND ( playerpos='(".$pos_others[0].")'";
for($i=1;$i<count($pos_others);$i++){
    $query.=" OR playerpos='(".$pos_others[$i].")'";
}
$query.=')';

$query = (string)$query;

echo $query;

    // the above outputs: 
/*$query = "SELECT * FROM allplayer 
        WHERE venueuuid='ID' 
           AND ( playerpos='(4.6, -4.9, 4.6)' 
           OR playerpos='(2.6, -4.9, 2.6)' 
           OR playerpos='(2.6, -4.9, 4.6)' 
           OR playerpos='(4.6, -4.9, 2.6)' 
           OR playerpos='(4.6, -4.9, 3.6)' 
           OR playerpos='(2.6, -4.9, 3.6)' 
           OR playerpos='(3.6, -4.9, 4.6)' 
           OR playerpos='(3.6, -4.9, 2.6)')"; */
   // putting this in mysql shell gives a nontrivial set of rows!

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    var_dump($row);

}

   // no results come out here! why????????

function pos2arr($p){
    $p=trim($p);
    $p=substr($p,1,strlen($p)-1);
    $p=str_replace(')','',$p);
    $p=str_replace('(','',$p);
    return explode(',',$p);
}
```

Comment: And if you hard code the $query = "..." does it work?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: yes, the hardcode works!! that's the oddity. but the generated doesn't work! o.O irony is that the hardcode copy/paste of the generated works as well... just not the generated by itself o.O

Comment: So if you echo the query, then copy and paste that exact query as $query, it works?  That's doesn't make sense >.<.  Are you sure you've selected the correct database in MySQL?  First thing that comes to mind is that you're running the query on two different databases.

Comment: it's the right database... because if i uncommment the $query, and use that instead of the generated, it returns results! ... it's just that the generated (which generated the commented $query) doesn't return results ...

Comment: $query is somehow being altered between generation and mysql_query call then.  From a logic/math point of view, the behaviour you're describing doesn't make sense otherwise....  Seems odd.  Is this the actual code, or a modified snippet btw?

Comment: And, as a side note, you should consider storing the locations as 3 separate fields rather than a string.

Comment: this is the actual... i'm thinking this may be some type conversion issue which was why i tried $query = (string)$query just to be sure the numerical operations didn't somehow affect the $query string in mysql_query... but no dice!

Comment: echo-ing query after the mysql_query... the echo returns the same results but somehow mysql is not calling...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9439/discussion-between-ina-and-corbin)