# Populating selection list based on prior entry

Tags: php, sql, database, populate

I have some PHP/SQL written to populate a selection list with data from a database with the option being populated based on a prior numeric entry in a text box. At the moment i gave it a go but i really don't know how to properly do it and currently this code doesn't work (doesn't display any options), so any advice would be great. Here is my code :

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****");
mysqli_select_db(twa312, $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysqli_error() );

$options = '<option value="0"></option>';
$postcode = $_POST["post"];

if (isset($postcode) && !empty($postcode)) {
$sql = "SELECT school_info.Name AS Name, valid_postcodes.postcode AS postcode FROM  school_info INNER JOIN local_schools ON local_schools.schoolID = school_info.schoolID";
$sql .= " JOIN valid_postcodes ON local_schools.postcodeID = valid_postcodes.id ";
$sql .= " where postcode = '$postcode' ";

$rs = mysqli_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysqli_error());

echo "<pre>";
print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs));
echo "</pre>";
mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
$name=$row["Name"];
$options .= '<OPTION VALUE="' . $name . '">' . $name ."</option>";
}

?>

<form name="eoiform" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="eoi">

<b>Post Code</b>
<br>
<input type="text" id="post" name="post" /><?php echo $msgp; ?>

<b>Student's Current Primary School</b>
<br>
<select name="primary" id="primary"><?php echo $options; ?></select>

</form>
```

What i am essentially trying to do is populate the selection list "primary" with a list of school names from a database based on the postcode entered in the "post" field, so meaning of course it should search the database for schools with the same postcode as entered. The name of the schools are in the table "school_info" as the column "Name" and the list of postcodes are in the table "valid_postcodes" as the column "postcode". These two tables are connected by columns in a third table being "local_schools". with the problem that i may not explain everything properly i have taken a screenshot and edited to show the link between the three tables which should hopefully clarify things about the link :

[image]

So the "id" column in "valid_postcodes" (where the postcodes are) is connected to the "postcodeID" column in "local schools" and the "id" column in "local_schools" is connected to the "schoolID" column in "school_info" which is where the names of the schools are.

Could anyone help me with a solution for this, i'm quite new to these languages so i am having quite a bit of trouble so any help would be great. If i haven't made something clear enough or left some information out just tell me.

Also here is the result to the print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));

```
Array
(
[Name] => St Marys Primary School
[postcode] => 2747
)
```

Comment: If you have only 1 row returned, by using `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));` first, then when you do `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs))` it is trying to get the 2nd returned row, which there is none - `Returns an associative array ... and moves the internal data pointer ahead.` Try either removing `echo "<pre>"; print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)); echo "</pre>";` or use [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) - `mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);` before `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) { ...` to reset back to the first returned row.

Comment: so just add mysql_data_seek($rs, 0); before the whole loop?

Comment: yes, if you keep the `print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))` in your script you need to add `mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);`. Once you remove that, then you can remove the `mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);` as well. Here is an odd, but vivid explanation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5750181/689579

Comment: will this allow me to display the value in the selection list though?

Comment: If your posted results of `print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));` are correct, then yes you should be able to display the value in the selection list using `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {...`

Comment: by adding the line mysql_data_seek($rs, 0); ?

Comment: i have added it in my original post, do you mean add it like that?

Comment: or should i just remove it all together?

Comment: If you know that you are returning rows, you can remove the `print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs));` & `mysql_data_seek($rs, 0);` as those are typically used to debug. Your `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {...` should work to display the value in the selection list

Comment: thats the thing though, when i enter a valid postcode and click on the selection list to choose an option, nothing is displayed

Comment: that's why i used the print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)); to see if anyhthing was returning and it seems like there was but it just wouldn't populate the list

Comment: do i need to add some form of onblur/onchange type thing?

Comment: because i don't want it to change on submit

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to type in the `post` input, and then have the `select` populate without posting/submitting the form?