# While loop in another while loop to echo data from SQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have 2 tables, table 1 and table 2.
I want to echo all in table 1, an each time I echo all in table 1 I want to echo all in tabel 2.
I know I can't write a code this form:

```
while($var = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     echo $var['data'];
     while($var2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
     {
       echo $var2['data2'];
     }
}
```

So how am I supposed to write the code ???

Comment: why can't you write code like that... seems sensible to me... although combining the queries into one would probably yield better performance.

Comment: You can't put one mysqli_fetch_assoc in another

Comment: you can get all rows first, then iterate through them,,,

Comment: Tell me how, write me a good code in a response

Comment: I tried it doesn't work

Comment: So long as you are not trying to use it on the same resource, you can use it multiple times.  See this delicious answer for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5750181/1618257

Comment: I tried it though it didn't work

Comment: It doesn't work because you haven't bothered reading the comments/ansswers in your original question. You are RUNNING THE SECOND QUERY INCORRECTLY.

Comment: @SamiK MarcB's solution on the reference duplicate sums up the issue you are having pretty completely.

Comment: How I am running it incorrectly ??

Comment: I don't get why it isn't working then